# Rotate a Bitmap without using an ImageURI/ContentResolver?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, rotation, uri

I am trying to adapt Microsoft's projectOxford EmotionApi's image-auto rotater code. Each image taken by the device camera is analyzed for its angle, and then rotated to the correct landscape view to be analyzed by the emotion API.

My question is : how would I adapt the code below to take a Bitmap as an argument? I am also completely lost as to the role of the Content Resolver and ExitInterface in this case. Any help is well appreciated.

```
private static int getImageRotationAngle(
        Uri imageUri, ContentResolver contentResolver) throws IOException {
    int angle = 0;
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(imageUri,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            angle = cursor.getInt(0);
        }
        cursor.close();
    } else {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageUri.getPath());
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                angle = 270;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                angle = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                angle = 90;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return angle;
}

// Rotate the original bitmap according to the given orientation angle
private static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int angle) {
    // If the rotate angle is 0, then return the original image, else return the rotated image
    if (angle != 0) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    } else {
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how would I adapt the code below to take a Bitmap as an argument?

You can't.

> I am also completely lost as to the role of the Content Resolver and ExitInterface in this case

The code in your question uses the EXIF `Orientation` tag to determine the orientation that should be applied to the image, as reported by the camera that took the photo (or whatever set that tag). `ExifInterface` is code to read EXIF tags. `ExifInterface` needs to work with the actual JPEG data, not a decoded `Bitmap` — a `Bitmap` no longer has the EXIF tags.

The `ContentResolver` code in there is bug-riddled and should not be used. The `ExifInterface` that comes in the `com.android.support:exifinterface` library has a constructor that takes an `InputStream`, from which it will read the JPEG. The correct way to use the `Uri` here is to pass it to `openInputStream()` on the `ContentResolver`, passing that stream to the `ExifInterface` constructor.

Comment: Understood, thank you for the thorough explanation. Any recommendations on rotating a bitmap?

Comment: @A.Xu: Well, the `rotateBitmap()` method in your question will rotate the bitmap. The point behind the whole EXIF header stuff is to determine if a JPEG should be rotated and, if so, by how much.